# Passing directives to Component in Angular 1.5

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

I'm currently using `Angular 1.5` library and wants to create a component for simple Text Box like below.

#### Component JS

```
'use strict';

angular
    .module('components')
    .component('inputBox', {
        bindings: {
            label: '@',
            name: '@',
            type: '@',
            classes: '@',
            placeholder: '@',
            maxlength: '@'
        },
        controllerAs: 'field',
        templateUrl: 'app/components/inputBox.html'
    });
```

#### Component Template

```
<input type="{{field.type || 'text'}}"  
            class="form-control {{field.classes}}" 
            id="{{field.name}}" 
            name="{{field.name || 'unnamed'}}" 
            maxlength="{{field.maxlength}}" 
            placeholder="{{field.placeholder}}" />
```

#### Usage in all Templates.

```
<input-box 
    label="Enter an account"
    name="accountNumber"
    type="number"
    classes="form-control"
    placeholder="Account Number"
    maxlength="20"

    // directives
    ng-model="accountNumber"
    ng-custom1="value1" 
    ng-custom2="value2" 
    ng-custom-validator="value4" />
```

I have two issues which is below where i need the best practices.

1. I want to keep all directives extended in the usage template not part of component.
2. Which is best practice `@` or `=` but i good understanding about this options.

   a. "@" ( Text binding / one-way binding )

   b. "=" ( Direct model binding / two-way binding )

   c. "&" ( Behaviour binding / Method binding )

> Why this approach?
>
> I have around 27 forms with many input types. I want to create the single component that will have all field label, input and error container.

Answer (score 1):

There are some things quite confusing or just wrong:

You are passing the name of your model like

```
<input-box modelname="account.number"...
```

and try to use it with:

```
<input type="{{field.type || 'text'}}" 
        ng-model="account.number" ...
```

You are not using your modelname, instead you are trying to access a object variable `account.number` which is not defined (at least it is not defined in your example) this is not dynamic anymore.

If you want to pass your model directly do something like:

```
angular
.module('components')
.component('inputBox', {
    bindings: {
        model: '=',
        ...
    },
    controllerAs: 'field',
    templateUrl: 'app/components/inputBox.html'
});
```

with

```
<input-box model="account" ... />
```

And in your component template:

```
<input ng-model="model" ... />
```

Regarding your second question: you can´t do

```
<input ... {{field.attribs}} />
```

You could use attrs for that and copying them to your input element:

```
angular
.module('components')
.component('inputBox', {
    bindings: {
        model: '=',
        ...
    },
    controllerAs: 'field',
    templateUrl: 'app/components/inputBox.html',
    controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        angular.forEach($attrs, function(key, value){
            $element[key] = value;
        });
    }
});
```

At least i am wondering why to wrap an input element into a component and do nothing more than copy the properties, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. updated my question whatever you are looking for ? BTW, your answer is not answer the question

Answer (score 0):

The Angular team recommends scope isolation for components by using one-way binding `<`or `@` rather than two-way binding `=`.  In terms of getting values out of a component, the recommendation is to use events.

Full details [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) under the section *Component based application architecture*